# How to hide the Go plus panel in Atom IDE?

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom editor I have installed Go plus package for GO autocomplete. After installing this package, Go autocomplete is working fine, but when the file is saved, the Go plus panel appears from the bottom.

How to hide it permanently?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the level of "hiding" that you desire. In my opinion there are three levels of hiding. All three can be modified by opening Edit --> Preferences --> Packages --> go-plus --> Settings, and then scrolling down to Panel.

1. The first level is hiding the panel on opening a new file, but it still appears upon saving a file. You can enable this by changing the `Panel Display Mode` that has a menu selection (the first one) to `closed`.
2. The second level is additionally hiding the panel on saving, but it still appears when a file is saved and has issues. You can enable this by changing the `Panel Display Mode` that has an input text box (the last one) to `hidden`.
3. The third level is additionally hiding the panel on saving when there are issues in a file. You can enable this by untoggling the checkbox off for the `Focus the go-plus panel on failure` option.

With all three of these, you can basically make it so the panel never shows up if that is what you really want. Note that because go-plus is using the Atom-Linter suite of packages behind the scenes, you will still have notifications from go-plus packages showing up in the Linter panel, and would need to disable those in the Linter-Ui-Default --> Settings (such as Hide Panel When Empty, Show Panel, etc.).

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I followed above steps But, I didn't find out those options in header. can you help me please?